# Appropriate set notation

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation

I have little problem reading math, but I sometimes feel like I'm illiterate when I come to write it. This is probably quite basic, but I can't find a good source to explain it. I'm probably just not searching under the right terms.

I have a set F which is a subset of non-negative integers and I am trying to write the following:

"There exists some $n$ such that if the number $i$ is an element of the set $F$, and $i+n\leq max(F)$, then this implies that $i+n$ is also in the set $F$."

What I have is something like this:

$$ \exists n \mid i \in F, i+n \leq max(F) \Rightarrow i+n \in F $$

I have thought of putting in parenthesis:

$$ \exists n \mid \big( i \in F, i+n \leq max(F) \big) \Rightarrow (i+n) \in F$$

Basically, can anyone confirm whether I'm on the right track? I normally write all of this stuff in programs and pseudo-code (yes, I'm one of those people), so I'm really rusty on proper mathematical notation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "$\mid$" symbol means "such that" in the set language; we use it in the context :

> $\{ x \mid P(x) \}$

that reads : "the set of those $x$ such that $P$ holds of them".

In a formula, you do not use it; what is appropriate are parentheses; thus :

> $∃n \ [(i \in F \land (i+n ≤ max(F))) \to (i+n) \in F]$.

Comment: Thanks. I actually don't have the $\exists n \mid$ in my draft; I write that bit in words. I just thought I'd go for broke when I asked the question. So the parenthesis surrounds everything the $\exists n$ relates to; handy to know. Is the comma acceptable as a stand-in for $ \cap $, or is that only in set-builder notation?

Comment: I'm typing this on my phone, so mathjax might be a bit beyond me. The only reason I wanted to keep using commas instead of and was for consistency. This is going to be a document among others already authored. The others tend to use commas, which I've always read as an implicit "and", but appropriate only in certain circumstances.

Answer (score 1):

Something that holds for all $i$ in some set should get the "$\forall. $"  So write $$\exists n \forall i\in F (i+n\leq \max F\implies i+n\in F) . $$ Note that the "such that" or the "for which" between the "$\exists n$" and the "$\forall i$" is not written  and usually isn't .And that  immediately following "$\forall i\in F$" the words "such that" are also implicit but  not stated.

Comment: Ah, but the catch here is it isn't for all $i \in F$. For some $i \in F$, $i+n > max(F)$. For example, sine $n \in \mathbb{Z^*}$, if I select the largest element in set F, then for any selection of $n$ $i+n > max(F)$

Comment: Sorry, I meant $n \in \mathbb{Z^+}$. I don't state that here, but it wasn't relevant to the question.